# Where can we use dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

We would like to use `dictionary` in our project but we don’t know exactly in which scenario we can use the dictionary.

Kindly someone assists with it and explain where we can use it in the project.

Comment: https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/11/25/insertion-of-sitecore-dictionary-item-and-usage/

Comment: Why would you use something if you don't have a reason to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Sitecore Dictionary is useful when translating hard-coded text like form labels, button texts, watermarks, validation messages. Sitecore Dictionary supports Multi-lingual. Dictionary allows creating key-value pair.

you can find more details here:

https://sagittarius.agency/en/our-thinking/blog/sitecore-dictionaries-fields-and-translations
http://rajsitecore.blogspot.com/2018/11/sitecore-dictionaries.html

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore Dictionary is particularly useful when you are dealing with multi-lingual sites. You can definitely go with configuration items instead. But when you want to render only textual key phrases in various places across your site, the Dictionary comes in very handy.

Advantages:

- You do not have to create any templates explicitly.
- You can use the helper methods offered by Sitecore to render the Dictionary values.
- As the items are just Key-Value phrases, Import-Export tools can be easily written to add content for your multi-lingual sites. (A particularly useful perk.)